# Quebra de linhas em um atributo data ao exibir no front-end

Tags: php, html, front-end

Dentro de uma tabela eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<td>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Dados" data-trigger="focus"
data-content=" <?php 
echo $BlobParams[0].'<br>';
echo $BlobParams[1].'<br>';
echo $BlobParams[2].'<br>';
echo $BlobParams[3].'<br>';
echo $BlobParams[4].'<br>';
echo $BlobParams[5].'<br>';
echo $BlobParams[6];
?>">
Parametros
</a>
</td>
```

No `data-content` aparecem dados de um *array*, gostaria que aparecesse um item abaixo do outro. Tentei usar o `<br>` de diversas formas, mas não deu certo. O `<br>` aparece escrito na tela.

Comment: O que está utilizando para exibir essa mensagem? Ele possui suporte a elementos HTML?

Comment: Já tentou a constante pré-definida `PHP_EOL` no lugar de <br> ? Assim: `echo $BlobParams[0]. PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Você terá que por a quebra de linha "dentro da varável".

Comment: Você busca essa quebra ao exibir o código da página, certo?

Comment: Já tentou com '\r' ou '\n' ? Pode ser que isso te ajude https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_linha

Answer (score 0):

PHP_EOL é ostensivamente usado para encontrar o caractere de nova linha de uma maneira compatível com várias plataformas. PHP_EOL representa o caractere de finalização para o sistema atual, diferente de uma tag de marcação html como a tag `<br>`.

Constante pré-definida PHP_EOL(string) - 'End Of Line'. Disponível desde o PHP 5.0.2, segundo o manual do PHP.

Uso no seu caso:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Dados" data-trigger="focus"
            data-content="<?php echo PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[0]. PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[1]. PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[3]. PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[2]. PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[4]. PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[5]. PHP_EOL .
                            $BlobParams[6]; ?>"> Parametros</a> 
</td>
```

Comment: Olá... agradeço a ajuda... porém os dados continuam aparecendo um ao lado do outro.

Comment: A nivel de curiosidade e também não sei se é a melhor forma, consegui solucionar o caso da seguinte forma na chamada da função " $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true}); ",  adicionei o html:true.  Com isso pude usar o <br> normalmente.

Comment: Você pode responder a sua própria pergunta com a solução que encontrou e seleciona-la como resposta correta para seu problema.

Comment: Em sua questão, poderia juntamente com o código por um print(tela) do seu problema. E na resposta, também um print com o problema resolvido e mais o código. Acho que ficaria mais claro. Saudações.

Answer (score 0):

A nível de curiosidade e também não sei se é a melhor forma, consegui solucionar o caso da seguinte forma na chamada do método `popover`:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true})
```

Adicionei o `html:true` que fez com que eu pudesse usar o `<br>` normalmente.

Comment: Eu fiquei curioso. Poderia depois por um print da tela. O que realmente mudou e como estava antes.

Comment: Na verdade nesse campo aparece os parametros (filtros usados para geração de um relatório), e esses ítens estavam aparecendo todos um ao lado do outro apenas separado pro " - " ,  e estava  bem confuso. Então surgiu a idéia de separar cada ítem do Array em uma linha.

Comment: Isso ao passar o mouse sobre o link? Digo isso, pois no teste que fiz ele quebra os itens por linha, mas somente na visualização do código. De qualquer forma, que bom que resolveu o problema.

Comment: Seria ao clicar mesmo ..... clica aparece um popover com as informação e clicando em qualquer lugar ele fecha. Apenas  pra não ficar muitas informações na tela. Então elas só aparecem quando o usuário clica em cima.

Answer (score 0):

Uma nova alternativa para a escrita dos dados. Caso a pessoa não use algum parâmetro de filtro, esse não irá aparecer e nem ficará uma linha em branco

```html
<?php
foreach($BlobParams as $blobs){
if($blobs != ""){
echo "- ".$blobs."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria interessante você adaptar seu código da seguinte forma:

Adicione a option `html: true` na chamada do popover.

```js
// Habilita o html no conteúdo do popover
$('#example').popover({html: true})
```

```html
<td>
  <?php
    $content = '';

    // Cria o conteúdo com <br> de forma dinâmica
    foreach($BlobParams as $BlobParam) {
      $content .= $BlobParam . '<br>';
    }

    // Remove o espaçamento <br> no final da string 
    $content = rtrim($content, '<br>');
  ?>
  <a 
    href="#" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    title="Dados" 
    data-trigger="focus"
    data-content="<?php echo $content; ?>">
    Parametros
  </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você tbm pode definir o valor do atributo como um json com todo o array `$BlobParams`.
Dessa maneira foca mais fácil de recuperar os valores no js.